# Will google crawl or index if API is disallowed in robots.txt

Tags: android, api, reactjs, sitemap, google-search

I want googlebot to index urls that are added dynamically to my sitemaps. Urls that I add are for profiles (`example.com/username`), blogs, etc...  I use server-side rendering with react-router, and some components make `api` calls to `api.example.com/...`. After reading the docs about crawling and `robots.txt`. I had an understanding that googlebot makes requests to links as it crawls the page. Therefore the server gets requests from `googlebot.com` and `googlebot` also interacts with `robots.txt` in process.

Well, I don't want google to crawl my api or people linking to it. This would overload the server. And Instagram does exactly the same https://instagram.com/robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /api/
```

Due to my understanding, I am a bit confused how google crawls pages of public profiles (google "Kelly Slater instagram").

Also, https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/enabling-app-indexing.html#robots (last paragraph - bottom of page) says I need to instead allow google to make requests to `/api/`.

Questions

1. Because `/api/` is blocked, how google crawls Instagram pages? Does it wait for the response from the server and ignores `robots.txt` since it's an indirect request coming from another page?
2. Is web crawling different to app crawling? And do I need to instead enable `/api/` to make my future android app crawlable?
3. I also noticed Instagram does not have `Sitemap: ...` field in their `robots.txt`. Do they submit their sitemap using apis of search engines like `google ping` or not?

Answer (score 0):

There's kind of a lot of questions going on in this post, but we recently ran into this, and to summarize:

- First Google loaded our initial HTML page.
- It then treated API calls as 499 errors, and closed the connections before retrieving a response.
- If the page required data from the blocked API URLs, it was not fetched, and thus (on our site) did not load the page properly.

So if you want Google to still crawl a page but without the necessary API calls, be sure to have a fallback or to block the page from being crawled in the first place.